# Constructive proof that the sum of a rational and an irrational is irrational

Tags: elementary-number-theory, constructive-mathematics

I want to prove this constructively (ie, without using contradiction), and I tried to prove the contrapositive, that if a + b is rational then it can not be the case that WOLOG a is rational and b is irrational, but that proof also seems to lend itself to contradiction.

For an example of what I am looking for, consider this constructive proof that $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational under the header "Constructive Proof" in this wikipedia article: [$\sqrt{2}$ is irrational](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root_of_2#Proofs_of_irrationality)

Comment: What do you mean by constructive? If you had to prove that something is rational, then I would understand: "provide $p$ and $q$ such that this thing is $p/q$". But to prove that $p$ and $q$ don't exist, being constructive doesn't seem to make sense.

Comment: I guess I just mean without using the law of the excluded middle, ie no contradiction proofs.

Comment: Also there are constructive proofs for the fact that $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational, for example, so it can be done.

Comment: Really? Do you have a reference? I would love to see that!

Comment: The one I've seen is beautiful. The easiest place to find it is in the wikipedia article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root_of_2#Proofs_of_irrationality it is under the section titled "Constructive Proof"

Comment: Really nice, I learned something today!

Comment: Also, I think that you should include this example in the body of the question, it would be a great context.

Comment: I don't see how that cited proof that $\sqrt 2$ is irrational can be consider not to be proof by contradiction.  The proof points out that $\sqrt 2$ is integer or irrational.  ANd it's not an integer so...  That's a proof by contradiction in *my* book.

Comment: And the classical proof of infinite descent is *definitely* a proof by contradiction.

Comment: I think you're looking at the wrong proof. The constructive one just shows the distance between root 2 and an arbitrary rational is strictly positive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a simple proof adapted from the example you gave of the irrationality of $\sqrt 2$.

Assume $a$ is a rational and $b$ an irrational. Then for any integers $p,q$ with $q\neq 0$ you have $$|(a+b)-\frac pq|=|b-\left(\frac pq-a\right)|$$
which is positive since $\frac pq-a$ is a rational and $b$ is not.

Since the distance between any rational and $a+b$ is positive, $a+b$ is not a rational.

Comment: Awesome dude thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I also thought of another proof. We want to prove the contrapositive, that if $a + b$ is rational then $a$ is irrational or $b$ is rational. This is equivalent to the statement that $a$ is rational implies $b$ is rational, which is true since $b = (a + b) - a$, and by assumption both $a + b$ and $a$ are rational and since the rationals are closed under subtraction we have that $b$ is rational.